# Scanner and Buffered reader not showing double quotation marks Java Android

Tags: java, android, text, bufferedreader

I'm trying to load from a .txt file. Like most .txt files, it's UTF-8 encoded, so it shows double-quotation mark characters when I load it inside of eclipse.

The problem is, when I load my text file into bufferedreader (also set to UTF-8 encoding), it converts double quotation marks and a few other characters into question mark boxes on my device.

I can't figure out what could be the problem, searches here and on Google are all talking about Arabic characters. Please help.

edit: ... updating question... one minute

edit2: I'm displaying them inside a TextView.
The following is from a method. Scanner wasn't working either so I used this:

```
 InputStream in;
 in = getResources().openRawResource(R.id.text);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
 ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>(25);
        try {
            String line="";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] splited = line.split("\\s+");
                int m = 0;
                String word="";
                        while(m<splited.length){
                       m++; // analyze the word and do some other stuff here
                       letters.add(word);
                       }

            }
            in.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is where I display my text inside a handler:

```
                  final Textview txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.something);
                 // handler stuff, then inside the handler:
               txt.setText(word, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                  Spannable s = (Spannable)txt.getText();
                   s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFFFF),2,3,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I removed the spannable, no dice.

Comment: Please show the code you're using, the kind of double-quotes you're using (I suspect they're not the ASCII ones), and what the *bytes* look like in the file.

Comment: It is entirely possible that `BufferedReader` is reading the characters just fine, and they are only being shown as the 'missing glyph' character because of the way you're displaying them. "Like most .txt files, it's UTF-8 encoded" -- ah, if only *that* were true.

Comment: (Note: double quote characters include U+0022, U+201C, U+201D, and, less likely, U+201E, U+201F, and U+2E42.)

Comment: Okay. I think I made my last edit. Note that Scanner wasn't working either and that each quotation mark are at the beginning or end of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what you default notepad saves your txt files as, just go to file>>save as, then along the bottom or in some kind of options menu there should be something about character encoding